# What does this sentence mean: "Keep right behind me"

Tags: sentence-meaning

While I was reading a book I saw **"Keep right behind me"** sentence. And I don't know what it means. A man was saying this sentence to a woman. Could you explain this sentence in basic English for an English learner.

Comment: If you're concerned about an answer, I believe you should be able unclick the check mark at any time (not sure). Anyway, we typically recommend waiting a day or two before accepting. See [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/36187)

Answer (score 2):

"Right" can be used as an adverb meaning 'exactly' or 'just'. If someone is right behind you, that person is close behind you. Likewise they could be right next to you, or right in front of you.

> right
>   adverb
>   (EXACTLY)   exactly; just:
>   I’m too busy to talk right now but I’ll get
>   back to you later.
>   He sat right behind me.
>   I’ll be right back (= I
>   will return very soon).

[Right (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/right)